# Spring Boot OAuth2ResourceServer with one or two Jwt token

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I am having a hard time trying to find an appropriate solution for my use case since I can't seem to find documentation about this. The closest I could find that relates a little to my issue would be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40627561/spring-cloud-oauth2-resource-server-with-multiple-authorization-server).

#### Here's a little summary of my situation

All of our Spring Boot microservices are using an `OAuth2ResourceServer` configured with our internal provider (let's call it **Provider A**). That way, only other microservices (configured with an OAuth2 WebClient) or employees can send requests to our microservices. So far, I got this working without any problem.

The problem I am facing is that some endpoints of our microservices require an additional token (**Provider B**) in order to authorize our customers (eg. to access or modify their data).

As such, all HTTP requests that are sent to our microservices includes an `Authorization` header for our **Provider A**. On the other hand, some of those HTTP requests also have an `CUSTOMER_TOKEN` header for our **Provider B**.

**My question**

How would one configure Spring Boot so that the `OAuth2ResourceServer` support 1 or 2 Jwt tokens from two different issuers? Any pointers or better solutions for this?

**What I've attempted**

So far, I've tried a couple of things which feels hacky and I suspect I am doing something wrong or I am just not looking in the right direction.

The *best* solution that I have come up with consists of an `OAuth2ResourceServer` configured with a custom `Customizer<OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer<HttpSecurity>>`, a custom `AuthenticationManagerResolver`, a custom `AccessDeniedHandler`, a custom `AuthenticationEntrypoint`, and two `JwtDecoder` configured with their respective JWK Set URIs and Issuer URIs:

```
  @Bean
  protected SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity)
      throws Exception {
    return httpSecurity.csrf()
        .disable()
        .cors()
        .configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource())
        .and()
        .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(WHITELIST)
        .permitAll()
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .oauth2ResourceServer(configurer -> 
          configurer
              .authenticationManagerResolver(authenticationManagerResolver())
              .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint())
              .accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler());
        )
        .build();
  }

  @Bean
  public AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler(){
    return (request, response, accessDeniedException) -> {
      response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
      response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
      response.setCharacterEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
      PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
      writer.write("\"message\": \"access denied\"");
      writer.flush();
    };
  }

  @Bean
  public AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint(){
    return (request, response, authenticationException) -> {
      response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
      response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
      response.setCharacterEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
      PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
      writer.write("\"message\": \"unauthorized\"");
      writer.flush();
    };
  }

  @Bean
  protected AuthenticationManagerResolver<HttpServletRequest>
      authenticationManagerResolver() {
    return request ->
        authentication -> {
          List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>(); // merged authorities
          Map<String, Object> attributes = new HashMap<>(); // merged attributes
          
          Authentication providerA = authenticate(request, OAuth2Provider.PROVIDER_A, authorities, attributes);
          
          if (request.getHeader(OAuth2Provider.PROVIDER_B.getHeader()) == null) {
            // If Provider B token is not in the request, the user won't have the appropriate role
            // to access endpoints annotated with @RoleAllowed(CUSTOMER_ROLE)
            return providerA;
          }
          
          return authenticate(request, OAuth2Provider.PROVIDER_B, authorities, attributes);
        };
  }

  public final Authentication authenticate(
      HttpServletRequest request,
      OAuth2Provider oAuth2Provider,
      List<GrantedAuthority> authorities,
      Map<String, Object> attributes) {
    Jwt jwt = decodeAccessToken(request, oAuth2Provider); // JwtDecoder + error handling

    authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(oAuth2Provider.getRole()));
    authorities.addAll(getTokenAuthorities(jwt));

    Map<String, Object> providerAttributes = new HashMap<>(jwt.getClaims());
    providerAttributes.put("token", jwt);
    attributes.put(oAuth2Provider.getName(), providerAttributes);

    OAuth2AuthenticatedPrincipal principal =
        new DefaultOAuth2AuthenticatedPrincipal(attributes, authorities);
    
    OAuth2AccessToken accessToken =
        new OAuth2AccessToken(
            TokenType.BEARER, jwt.getTokenValue(), jwt.getIssuedAt(), jwt.getExpiresAt());

    return new BearerTokenAuthentication(principal, accessToken, authorities);
  }
```

This solution works, per se, but feels hacky to me since I need to manually reply with 401 or 403, which is not really a good sign when dealing with security. Also `HttpServletRequest` seems to have been dropped from Spring 3.x, which kind of amplifies my feeling of hackyness and the possibility of better solutions.

Comment: Why do you add a token from provider A to customer requests? Why don't you just propagate the token issued by provider B and configure your resource servers to accept tokens from both A & B issuers? That way, all you'd have to do is define access control rules based on roles and issuer.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I've taken into consideration your pointer and actually decided to follow something along the lines you mentioned. As such, I am configuring endpoint paths with the appropriate resource server, there's just a long road ahead in this journey ;).

Comment: [Those tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials) I wrote could ease your journey